# How to design a list item of listview

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

I have a list view with Two text labels and three image buttons on each row. Visually, I want each row to look like this:

[image]

But I can't get this to work in my layout. This is what I'm doing right now. Even though the two labels are showing up ok, the buttons are not showing as I want them to.

**Question**

How can I align the buttons as in the mockup?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/track_no"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/shade_count"
    android:layout_below="@id/shade_count"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shade_count"
        style="@style/ListSubtitleText"
        android:textColor="#ff868686"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/star"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/share"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Red Color" 
                android:textColor="#000000"                    
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
                android:text="this color has 20 shodes" 
                android:textColor="#ff868686"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/share" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="Red Color"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip"
                android:text="this color has 20 shodes"
                android:textColor="#ff868686" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/star" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:src="@drawable/share" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:src="@drawable/delete" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```